# Mostrar una imagen dando click en un button? .Swift

Tags: swift

Quiero hacer un memorama pero la verdad no se ni donde empezar, quiero cuando le de click al button "Ver" aparezca la imagen ICB ojala me puedan ayudar de antemano gracias
[image: mEMORAMASWIFT]

Comment: por favor agrega el código cómo `texto` y no una imagen

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta, algunos usuarios del sitio no pueden visualizar el código en la imagen, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIButton tiene States, el botón en su estado normal es el estado **default**, para que logres mostrar la imagen cuando se haga touch, tienes que asignar la imagen al botón en el estado **highlighted**

puedes probar lo siguiente, pero en un IBOutlet del botón:

```
@IBOutlet weak var demoButton: UIButton! {
    didSet {
        demoButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "machupichu"), for: .highlighted)
    }
}
```

Previamente tienes que cambiar el tipo de botón a modo **Custom** porque por default el tipo que se coloca en un botón creado via storyboard es **System** y ese ya tiene propiedades pre configuradas.

Otra opción es que lo hagas por storyboard:

Seleccionas el botón y en la sección de atributos lo configuras

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]